# Сформировать строку для cURL из аргументов

Tags: c++, curl

Строка для curl -> char*
Делаю так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* host;
    int port;
    cout << argv[0]; // имя программы 
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // начинаем с 1, пропуская имя программы
        if (i + 1 != argc) {
            if (argv[i] == "--host") { // встретили параметр host
                host = argv[i + 1];  // строка
            } else if (argv[i] == "--port") { // параметр port
                port = atol(argv[i + 1]); // int
            }
        }
    }

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode result;

    string url_from_arguments;
    url_from_arguments="http://www.myserver.ru/?port="+to_string(port)+"&host="+host;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_from_argumets.c_str());
}
```

если вывести:

```
cout << url_from_arguments;
```

выходят кракозябры, но строки вроде как добавляются

Как исправить создание ссылки из параметров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[i] == "--host"` сравнивает два указателя, а не строки, на которые они указывают. В результате неинициализированный указатель `host` так и остается неинициализированным, а его разименование приводит к неопределенному поведению. Инициализируйте

```
char * host{};
```

используйте специальную функцию сравнения строк

```
if(0 == strcmp("--host", argv[i]))
```

и не забудьте проверить, что host стал не нулевым.

Comment: Привести любой из аргументов к `std::string` и все дела. Будет c++-way.